# How can I only color exponents in MathTex?

Tags: latex, manim

When using Manim, how can I only color the exponents of a number in a `MathTex` object?

In the formula I want to color, all "1"s are written as powers.

```py
equation = r"\frac{6}{4^1-2}-\frac{5}{4^1+1}=2"
```

I have tried doing:

```py
obj = MathTex(equation, substrings_to_isolate="^1")
obj.set_color_by_tex("1", RED)
self.play(Write(obj))
```

But when executing the code, I get an error:

> LaTeX compilation error: Argument of \align* has an extra }.
> Context of error:
>
> ```
> \begin{document}
>
>  -> \begin{align*}
>
>   -2}-\frac{5}{4
>
>  \end{align*}
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way Manim works when splitting LaTeX code either with `isolate...`, double braces, as separate substrings or any other option is, that it sends the individual fragments to LaTeX for rendering.

However, some LaTeX commands like `\frac` cannot have their arguments split, because the resulting code is no valid LaTeX code anymore. One way is to use `a \over b` instead of `\frac{a}{b}`, but even that is not guaranteed to work flawlessly.

I would say that automation is not worth the effort most of the time, so you could just count the corresponding index position of your glyphs to be highlighted, the function `self.add(index_labels())` can help you here further:

```py
class testMathColor(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        matht9 = MathTex(
            r"\frac{6}{4^1-2}-\frac{5}{4^1+1}=2", 
        ).move_to([0, 0, 0])
        # uncomment to find indices
        self.add(matht9, index_labels(matht9[0]).set_color(RED).shift(0.15*UP))
        #matht9.set_color_by_tex("1", RED)
        #self.play(Write(matht9, run_time=1))
```

[image]

```py
class testMathColor(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        matht9 = MathTex(
            r"\frac{6}{4^1-2}-\frac{5}{4^1+1}=2", 
        ).move_to([0, 0, 0])
        # uncomment to find indices
        #self.add(matht9, index_labels(matht9[0]).set_color(RED).shift(0.15*UP))
        for i in [3,10]:
            matht9[0][i].set_color(RED)
        self.play(Write(matht9, run_time=1))
```

[image]

Come over to [Discord](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/faq/general.html?highlight=discord#where-can-i-find-more-resources-for-learning-manim) to learn more about other ways how to isolate and color parts of equations and/or in general about Manim.